# JavaScript spell check alert

Tags: javascript

How do I show user a JavaScript alert when they ignore spelling mistakes and try to submit a form, even after seeing the red under line. I want to implement this only when there is a spelling mistake actually.

Comment: @Nabil: [I beg to differ](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/editing.html#dom-spellcheck); though I've not found evidence of any JavaScript events fired upon submission of a field with faulty spelling (and `spellcheck` uses the user's own installe dictionary/dictionaries, so they may have deliberately added 'teh' and not want to correct to 'the').

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the js libraries i found, Try to integrate them with your code.
I will recommend afterthrdeadline js library.

http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=jQuery

http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/

Answer (score -1):

Here is a plugin with source code and live demo. Check it

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/Form_Spelling_Validation_On_Submit_Demo_using_JavaScript

Comment: Hi Sarath

This is exactly what i am looking for.
But can you please help me figure out what is 'all' ,

Comment: "all" means the plugin will check all the tags if you want to check for a particular area then you can specify that tag name or id . check this out  [http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/) and click on the source code

Comment: Yes I got it.Thanks a lot.


But everytime i submit the form , i see only the spell check alert ok coming up, despite of mistakes in my text area.It returns true always.

this line is never called ; $Spelling.SpellCheckAsYouType('all').
Thanks.

Comment: No its not.
It never returns false.
However in demo ,it seems to be working , but it never shows the ok alert.

Comment: Did you download the plugin.

Comment: Yes.
I added id to root of my application.

Comment: well let me check and will let you know

Comment: Hello @prashant it worked for me. May be you should check your coding